# Directly start youtube video play from mobile website

Tags: video, hyperlink, youtube, deep-linking

Right, second question here. Hope someone is able to help me out :)

I have made a mobile website for our company, it's basically a microsite that has a few pages, leading to 5 different categories that all have 2-7 links to youtube videos, each with an image of the item as sort of a "cover" - nicely stacked up under each other. The problem is, that with the links that I have inserted, using a standard , it sends the viewer on to youtube, and then they have to play the video from there. What I need help with is to "skip" the step of the users going to Youtube and having to press play, and enable viewers to press the "cover image" and the video loads up right there. So when they go back from full screen video, they will go back to my site, and not to youtube, having to press  back once more.

I doubt the code is necessary, but here is the div that I am using to link with:

```
<div class="box1">
<a href="http://youtu.be/k3FL7L9pkr4">
<div class="tekst">
<h4>Brioche Leather Jacket</h4>
<p>See details</p>
</div>
<img src="femme/sunny/2-brioche-jacket.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi im thinking if or how  i should give you all the code or not because its alot to give as a egsample i put a link on my website that plays this youtube video as an egsample http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EY-uM56BSrY to go see if this is what you want go to my website http://www.dmm.co.za/Videogal.aspx and click on the black tie video let me know if this is what you want and ill make a plan to post the code somehow

Answer (score 0):

you need to build in your own video player on your site then just use the link of the youtube video or try support.website-creator.org/stream_video.html
or try this it will put the link of the youtube directly onto your site

```
<embed
width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed>
```